# SingleTickerProviderStateMixin AppBar error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using https://pub.dev/packages/appbar_textfield with zero errors.

However, today I've been trying to run the app and I'm getting

> ../../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/appbar_textfield-1.0.1+1/lib/appbar_textfield.dart:674:41: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'.
> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

Is this fixable from my end with or without having to fork and edit the package?

Comment: maybe `flutter pub cache repair` ?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thank you very much. Running that in the Terminal has caused some Cocoa pod errors but I'll sort those out. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept and upvote? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Randal Schartz said, `flutter pub cache repair`